# Display submitted data using a select field option - webform module

Tags: webforms, forms

I'm new to Drupal. I have a form that I created using Webform Module, is there a way to pull data submitted by Webform and group it by a column. To display result in a view

Comment: What version of webform module are you using ?

Comment: @anilsagar the latest version 7.x-3.20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this topic should help you out. https://drupal.org/node/1658784 I used it when i needed to achieve the same thing.